# Como escolher aleatoriamente um item de um dicionário em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Gostaria de saber como escolher aleatoriamente um item de um dicionario em Python?

Por exemplo:

Tenho o dicionário

```
dic = {'Pedro': 99, 'João': 19, 'Rosa': 35, 'Maria': 23}
```

e preciso escolher um item aleatoriamente.

Comment: Por item você quer dizer a chave, o valor ou ambas as coisas?

Comment: Ambas, chave e valor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma maneira de fazer isso no Python 3 é obter uma [*view*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) dos items do dicionário e usar a função [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) para escolher um elemento.

```
import random
dic = {'Pedro': 99, 'João': 19, 'Rosa': 35, 'Maria': 23}
name, id = random.choice(list(dic.items()))
```

**Fonte**: [SOen - How to get a random value in python dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4859322/664577)